# Expresso-store sagepay errors

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, server, sagepay

Using sagepay_server gateway in test mode can get to payment page fine but on submit I get sagepay errors:

```
HTTP Status Code: 500
HTTP Status Message: The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.
Error Code : 5006
Error Description : Unable to redirect to Vendor's web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.
```

Return URL is in place in the checkout tag, using return="shop/order/ORDER_HASH" which usually works fine.

Settings for clients sagepay account are correct.

Comment: Can you email support@exp-resso.com about this? I think we will need to take a look at your website directly to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug - probably best if you email support@exp-resso.com so we can investigate it directly on your server.

Comment: Adrian, have emailed you 4 days ago, no response yet :(

Comment: Did you guys get to the bottom of this? I am getting the same error now unfortunately and would love to figure out where to go for a solution.